# So long and thanks for all the fish

Tags: discussion, moderators

I have resigned from the moderator team effective... whenever Grace finalizes things.

Change inevitably causes questions, so I'll do my best to summarize.  There's no big event or single person who led me to this decision.

Due to a combination of events on the site:

- Burnout in both meta discussions and flag handling
- A dearth of things to do post-election (owing to the awesomeness of the new mods)
- A dissatisfaction in the general direction of policies and attitudes of the site and the network
- An inability to change or accept the above, despite attempts to use my influence, and taking  self-imposed personal breaks

and in my personal life:

- Two houses
- Two jobs
- Three kids
- One wife

... I've come to a conclusion.  I'm not contributing positively as a moderator, and what contributions I am making are difficult for me.  It is better for everyone involved if I step down and take a big step back.

You guys are going to be fine without me!  If you need something, I'm where I always am.  Depending on how things go, I may continue to participate in non-mod ways.

Be Excellent To Each Other.

Comment: ............ :(

Comment: Oof! At least the numbers in your personal life match up. Imagine if you had one house, three jobs, two kids and two wives!

Comment: Is this because I had an affair with @John behind your back? I'm so sorry, I only meant to hurt you a little! [:(](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G71_3Pk4x2w)

Comment: ...I still haven't gotten used to seeing Oak without the little diamond on his name. :(

Comment: Poor @z '. He no longer has the highest non-mod rep!

Comment: Thanks for everything, agent86. You've been awesome.

Comment: We joined at the same time, and despite our titanic rep\ contribution difference, I always saw you silently as a peer. I'm sorry to see you go bro.

Comment: If it helps, you can keep @Wipqozn.

Comment: I haven't been there a long time but I've had enough time to see many of the thing you did for arqade. Good luck with your busy personnal life !

Comment: Will you still be checking in on the site? I assume this only means that you'll be stepping down from the role, but not the community.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the warm wishes.  I will probably be around, but at least at the beginning I need a bit of a break.  I like answering questions, though, so perhaps that will continue to be something I do when the mood strikes.

Comment: Could you explain further your thoughts on "a dissatisfaction in the general direction of policies and attitudes of the site and the network"? It could be helpful for the rest of us to understand the direction things are moving in.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt, No, it's intentional that I left it that way.  You can browse my meta history and see the sorts of things I tended to champion and the current state of those discussions if you'd like, but I don't want to get into another discussion/argument about them.  (That's specifically why I've resigned :P)  I've had long conversations about this with the other mods, with the community, and I communicated these things to the SE folks as well.