# So long and thanks for all the fish (again I guess)

Tags: discussion

I swear I had not seen [agent's post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9920/so-long-and-thanks-for-all-the-fish) until it came up on the related questions list when I finished typing the title.

Anyway, since the reason is the same I decided not to change it.

You may notice I don't have a diamond anymore, but you also probably noticed that I have not been around much lately, moderating or even participating lightly.

There are no special reasons, just life... it changes, unlike war.

It's been a long road since [2010-06-01 20:23:47Z](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1338/gaming) with ups and downs, fights, laughs, everything really.

So keep the site alive, and never allow ITG questions to return from the grave!

Comment: dang, that's the end of the original set of mods at gaming.se.

Comment: Why do mods keep resigning before we can work out their final score? bah! Thanks for your years of service, this place wouldn't be what it is without you. All us new mods are doing is looking after what you created.

Comment: I also just noticed agent's post today, while surfing through some old meta articles. When I noticed this in the latest questions page, I thought to myself "Waaat? How the hell did a year old article make it onto the latest questions list?". Then I noticed it was another post entirely. But anyway, thanks for your service, and good luck for the future!

Comment: Just an fyi, everytime a mod resigns, [I listen to this](https://vimeo.com/121619790).

Comment: Thanks @fredley, but all I did differently was create the area51 post, the site was created by all of us! Good luck and keep having fun!

Comment: I promise not to sue for copyright infringement on my title.  ;)  Enjoy your retirement, Juan!  You're welcome to come hang out with me anytime :D

Comment: @agent86 did you get the retirement package too? The free hats for life are the best thing

Comment: @juanformoso, not really a hat guy.  I opted for the "Free (As In Speech) Beer" which means I can do whatever I want with the beer once I've paid for it.

Comment: Fishes are made by everyone. You have a big portion of it. Thank YOU for the fish.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for all the work you've put in to the site when you were still active; I'm sure most of us truly appreciate them. I'm sure being a moderator is very much an 'Unsung hero' sort of thing, so thanks for all the time and effort you've put into improving the site!

Best of luck in your future StackExchange endeavors! :)